# Elixir - Creating JSON object from 2 collections

Tags: json, postgresql, tuples, elixir

I'm using [Postgrex](https://github.com/ericmj/postgrex) in Elixir, and when it returns query results, it returns them in the following struct format:

```
%{columns: ["id", "email", "name"], command: :select, num_rows: 2, rows: [{1, "me@me.com", "Bobbly Long"}, {6, "email@tts.me", "Woll Smoth"}]}
```

It should be noted I am using ***Postgrex directly WITHOUT Ecto.***

The columns (table headers) are returned as a collection, but the results (rows) are returned as a list of tuples. (which seems odd, as they could get very large).

I'm trying to find the best way to programmatically create JSON objects for each result in which the JSON key is the column title and the JSON value the corresponding value from the tuple.

I've tried creating maps from both, merging and then serialising to JSON objects but it seems there should be an easier/better way of doing this.

Has anyone dealt with this before?  What is the best way of creating a JSON object from a separate collection and tuple?

Comment: Apparently Postgres can render JSON for you directly, if you should run into performance problems: http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
result = Postgrex.query!(...)

Enum.map(result.rows, fn row ->
  Enum.zip(result.columns, Tuple.to_list(row))
  |> Enum.into(%{})
  |> JSON.encode
end)
```

This will result in a list of json objects where each row in the resultset is a json object.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much!  As a side note, is returning a Tuple as the result rows the most efficient way of doing things?  Result rows could, in theory, get very large and Tuples are inefficient when overly large are they not?  Just something I was wondering whilst working with Postgrex :)

Comment: Large tuples are only inefficient when you modify them since the whole tuple needs to be re-created then. If you are not modifying them it is the most efficient data type both space wise and in access time.

Comment: Looks promising but when I try to use this I get `exited in: :gen_server.call(Cool.Repo, {:checkout, #Reference<0.0.1.16613>, true, 15000}, 5000)`

Comment: @W.M. That's an unrelated error. The error is likely from `Postgrex.query!(...)` which I did not fill out.